# Violates RFC 2109: host > minus domain may not contain any dots

Tags: java, request, http-get

When I try to set a cookie to Apache httpget request I face with this:

> error.violates RFC 2109: host minus domain may not contain any dots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add below lines to code then problem solved.

```
httpGet.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);

httpGet.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2965);
```