# Karate - Cookie rejected when it contains special characters

Tags: karate

We are struggling to pass the response cookie to the subsequent request as we are getting Cookie Rejected error. We are also not able to print the cookie response:

Here are more details: giving req and response. See the Print at the very end prints nothing and at the start of response there are warning which we think is related to not printing response cookies.

```
 Scenario:                  
        * configure ssl = true
        Given url 'https://dvabc-qa.kdc.abc.com'
        Given path 'api/dp/v1/apps/user/login'
        And request {username: "test@abc.com", password: "1234"}
        When method post
        Then status 200
        * print responseCookies                                          
 Request                                                                       
1 > POST https://dvabc-qa.kdc.abc.com/api/dp/v1/apps/user/login
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 52
1 > Content-Type: application/json
1 > Host: dvabc-qa.abc.com
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_121)
{"username":"test@capone.com","password":"test1234"}                                  Response                                                                        14:48:30.700 [main] WARN  o.a.h.c.p.ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie rejected [X-AUTH-TOKEN="eyJ1c2VySW5mbyI6eyJ1c2VyRmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiVGVzdCIsInVzZXJMYXN0TmFtZSI6Ilh0ZXN0IiwidXNlcklEIjoiMTMxMTMx...", version:1, domain:.abc.com, path:/, expiry:null] Domain attribute ".abc.com" violates RFC 2109: host minus domain may not contain any dots
14:48:30.704 [main] WARN  o.a.h.c.p.ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie rejected [SSOID="test@abc.com", version:1, domain:.abc.com, path:/, expiry:null] Domain attribute ".abc.com" violates RFC 2109: host minus domain may not contain any dots
14:48:30.718 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - 
1 < 200
1 < CUSTOMER_APP_DATA_REF_KEY: $2a$10$qnUQ.paqXvMEJSmu6G/BhL7d08oOFnSAVmOBVQjec3Umlme
1 < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
1 < Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2017 18:48:32 GMT
1 < Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
1 < Pragma: no-cache
1 < SSOID: test@abc.com
1 < Set-Cookie: [X-AUTH-TOKEN="eyJ1c2VySW5joiVGVzdCwTaG93IjpudWxsLCJoYXNEaWFtb25kRGVhbGVyc2hpcHMiOmZhbHNlLCJub25EaWFtb25kRGVhbGVyQWNjZXNzRW5hYmxlZCI6ZmFsc2UsIm1mYVRva2VuIjpmYWxzZSwicmVzcG9uZGVkVG9BbGxUYyInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdEBjYXBvbmUuY29tIn0=.HzxYTNQGXk8n0HePKBcuk1ND5h6P8z4xvfaoJ5qah94="; Version=1; Domain=.abc.com; Path=/; HttpOnly, CUSTOMER_APP_DATA_REF_KEY=$2a$10$qnUQ.paPnsI9gqXvMEJSmu6G/BhL7d08oOFnSAVmOBVQjec3Umlme; Domain=.abc.com; Path=/; HttpOnly, SSOID="test@abc.com"; Version=1; Domain=.abc.com; Path=/; HttpOnly]
1 < Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
1 < X-AUTH-TOKEN: eyJ1c2VySW5mbyI6eyJ1c2VyRmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiVGVzdCIsInVzZXJMYXN0TmFtZSI6Ilh0ZXN0IiwidOiJ0ZXN0QGNhcG9uZS5jb20iLCJyYW5kb21UZXh0IjpudWxsLCJpbnRlcm5hbFVzZXJFbWFpbCI6bnVsbCwidXNlckRCJqb2JUaXRsZSI6IlNhbGVzIE1hbmFnZXIifSwiYWN0aXZlRGlyZWN0b3J5QWNjb3VudCI6ZmFsc2UsInRjVG9TaG93IjpudWxsLCJoYXNEaWFtb25kRGVhbGVyc2hpcHMiOmZhbHNlLCJub25EaWFtb25kRGVhbGVyQWNjZXNzRW5hYmxlZCI6ZmFsc2UsIm1mYVRva2VuIjpmYWxzZSwicmVzcG9uZGVkVG9BbGxUYyI6ZmFsc2UsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdEBjYXBvbmUuY29tIn0=.HzxYTNk1ND5h6P8z4xvfaoJ5qah94=
1 < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN                                      
14:48:30.719 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 583
14:48:30.726 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print]
```

Comment: as always, you really need to work on your issue description skills. how are you setting cookies. try setting them manually. if you have the request and response logs, do provide. jeez

Comment: @PeterThomas - I have made it more detailed this time. Apologies for not getting it detailed before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this may need a fix or enhancement to Karate.  Can you kindly file an enhancement request.

[Violates RFC 2109: host > minus domain may not contain any dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607324/violates-rfc-2109-host-minus-domain-may-not-contain-any-dots)

Meanwhile, can you try switching from `karate-apache` to `karate-jersey` in your `pom.xml` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas, i will have a enhancement request opened.

Comment: Thanks, updating pom.xml solved this. We were able to retrieve cookies.

Comment: @peter Thomas , switching from karate-apache to karate-jersey did solve the issue. Thanks!